# problems while installing perl modules !

Tags: perl

i have attempted to install DBI perl modules using cpan on RHEL with sudo. While installing am getting below error:

ERROR: Can't create '/usr/bin'
Do not have write permissions on '/usr/bin'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Thanks,
Mandy.
(email address removed)

Comment: it's done ! well i need to do sudo make install also.

Comment: well, actually although i was installing using sudo command [sudo -m mandy cpan -i DBI]...even after i need to explicitly run sudo command for make install !

Comment: I think this question should better be moved to serverfault.com. There may be additional security features in RHEL (like SELinux or extensive usage of `chattr +i`) which prevent even `root` from writing to certain locations. This has little to do with perl or cpan.

Comment: Also I suggest using `yum` for core modules like  `DBI` or `Tk`. Don't compile on RHEL unless you *absolutely* need it. Search for "perl dbi" package via RH's package system, then install their version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, use Yum/install the RPM for DBI yourself.

You should also [read this](http://www.twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/PerlOnRedHatIsSlow) report about a severe performance bug in RedHat's Perl package. It might have been fixed in the last releases of RHEL 5, but it's a show-stopper if it applies to you. That link contains a benchmark script which should tell you if it applies to you or not.

If it does, consider installing ActiveState's version of Perl.